# Change citep{} style from (NAME, YEAR) to (Name (YEAR))

Tags: cross-referencing

I a bloody nood regarding LaTeX and in the process of writing my bachelor thesis with it. However, my University has a citation standard, which i cannot achieve at the moment.
Following styles are used:

`\usepackage{cite}`
`\usepackage[round]{natbib}`
`\bibliographystyle{ecta1}`

Now if I want to make a corresponding reference (not a one to one citation) I normally use the following command (Shleifer 1993  as example):

`\citep{Shleifer1993}`

This shows up like this in the text:

(Shleifer, 1993)

What i would want is that it shows up like this:

(Shleifer (1993))

How do i do that? Thanks for an answer!
Kind Regards,
Seït

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

With some hacks, which should be independent from the bibliography style (I couldn't find `ecta1.bst`). Note that the `filecontents*` environment is just for making the example self-contained: you'll use your bib file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor2015,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\bibpunct{(}{\ifNAT@swa)\fi)}{;}{a}{ (\@gobble}{,}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citep{uthor2015}

\citet{uthor2015}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
\newcommand\citeP[1]{(\cite{#1})}
```

Comment: You may also want to provide the optional argument too.